# How to fetch records from solr those having spaces

Tags: solr

I have solr collection and stored a million documents inside. Name is one field in that document holding values along with multiple spaces (Dont know exactly space count). Need to gives name and ids for those records.

> For Ex:1. Name: "Arun  "
> 2. Name: "David "
> 3. Name: "Rahul" (correct record not require ID for this)

Please let me the fq.

Added Field details

```
<field name="CallSign"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Adding token details for field CallSign.

```
Field: CallSign
Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.TextFieldPI Gap:100Docs:20,719
Flags:  Indexed Tokenized   Stored  UnInvertible    Omit Norms
Properties  √   √   √   √   √
Schema  √   √   √   √   √
Index Analyzer:
org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain
Query Analyzer:
org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain
```

Comment: What is the field type and the analysis chain for that field? In many cases spaces will be lost, since they are used to break up the original text into tokens. In that case you'll probably have to either fetch every document with the field (the csv handler or /export endpoint will be fast for that), or possibly use a streaming expression: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/streaming-expressions.html

Comment: <field name="CallSign"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

Comment: @MatsLindh added field details

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to query that field in any meaningful way for spaces in a `fq`, since there won't be anything to match against - empty tokens aren't kept, so in effect you only have the `arun` token to match against (without any spaces). Look into exporting it through CSV and matching it manually or see if you can make it work with a streaming expression.

Comment: Found the solution. It worked with q=CallSign:*\s*   . Using this query solr fetching records having spaces only

Comment: @MatsLindh Please see the answer that I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my question. Lets consider field is Name

```
q=Name:*\s*
```

By using the above solr query it is fetching all documents whose names have space/spaces only.

Thank you all for you inputs.